# How to make a dictionary that counts repeated amount of length of any words from a file?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

How do I correct this so my dictionary reads length of a word = how many times the length of the word is repeated? Parameters is a file.

```
def wordLengths(fileName):
    d = {}
    f = open(fileName)
    filename.close()
    for line in f:
            for word in line:
                if len(word) not in d:
                    d[len(word)] = count.len(word)
    return(d)
```

Comment: No homework dude, just ask us a straight forward and simple question about it and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and where you've gotten stuck. A small chunk of code that almost works, but has a missing line saying "spam = # I don't know what goes here", and then some text afterward explaining what you tried for that line and why it didn't work (or, even better, actual code and output showing it failing) is a great question. Asking us to do the whole assignment for you is not.

Comment: OK, now that's a decent question. It would be even better if you knew where your code was first going wrong. You can find that out by learning to use the debugger, or an interactive visualizer, or by adding `print` calls throughout your code and reading the output until you see something surprising.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you've got a few mistakes. Let's look at them line by line.

```
def wordLengths(fileName): 
    d = {} 
    f = open(fileName)
```

So far, so good

```
    filename.close()
```

You can't close a filename—it's just a string. You can only close a file object, like `f`. Also, `filename` and `fileName` aren't the same thing; capitalization counts. Also, it's too early to close the file—you want to do it after reading all the lines, otherwise you won't get to read anything. So, scrap this line, and add a `f.close()` right before the `return`. (A `with` statement is even better, but you probably haven't learned those yet.)

```
    for line in f:
        for word in line:
```

When you loop over a string, you loop over each *character* in the string, not each word. If you want words, you have to call `line.split()`.

```
            if len(word) not in d:
                d[len(word)] = count.len(word)
```

Close, but not right. What you want here is: if the length isn't already in the dictionary, store 1; otherwise, add 1 to what's already there. What you've written is: if the length isn't already there, store the length (using some object that doesn't exist); otherwise, do nothing. So:

```
            if len(word) not in d:
                d[len(word)] = 1
            else:
                d[len(word)] += 1

    return(d)
```

That one's fine (but remember the `f.close()` above it). However, it's more idiomatic to write `return d`.

One more comment: You should be consistent with your indentation: always indent 4 spaces, not a random mix of 1, 4, and 7 spaces. It makes your code a lot easier to read—especially in Python, where indenting something wrong can change the meaning of the code, and that can be hard to spot when each indent level isn't consistent.